# How to add unity quicklist to my application?

Tags: application-development, quickly

How to add unity quicklist to my application? Is there any quickly command similar to quickly add indicator for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find this and more info on the [Ubuntu App Developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com). There is no Quickly command to add Quicklists, but they're pretty easy to create in code:

- Check out the [Launcher integration documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/launcher/) on Quicklists for the details.
- Watch the [Unity integration workshop](http://youtu.be/wqGfsgz1Sl4)